# How do I implement a relative frequency function in dask?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I am trying to use dask to get the count and relative percentages of category, grouped by label in the dataset below, so:

```
label    category      
a        1
a        2
a        3
b        1
b        1
b        2
```

would become:

```
label    category    count     percent
a        1           1         33.33333%  
a        2           1         33.33333%
a        3           1         33.33333%
b        1           2         66.66666%
b        2           1         33.33333%
```

Right now I'm doing this is 4 parts.

1. group the df by ['label', 'category'] and get the count as df1
2. group the resulting df1 by label and then sum the count
3. merge #1 with #2 to get the counts and the total
4. finally calculate the percentage using count and total

Am new to dask and pandas but my methodology seems inefficient, so wondering if there's a faster way to do this calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I can do ..still need two steps ...

```
df1=df.groupby(['label','category']).category.count().to_frame(name='count')
df1['percent']=df1.div(df1.groupby(level=0).sum(),level='label')*100

df1
Out[110]: 
                count    percent
label category                  
a     1             1  33.333333
      2             1  33.333333
      3             1  33.333333
b     1             2  66.666667
      2             1  33.333333
```

Comment: Ah great thanks, it was the `to_frame` piece I was missng!

Comment: @whisperstream  yw have a nice day